# How to make an image change its shape when pressed in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view, shapes

I've been trying to solve this for a while but I just can't seem to get a solution. What I want is that I press the image and it changes its shape. The mechanism through which it's done is that it's linked to an array of structures, with the "shapeNum" property deciding what number the shape is. I used [this example code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ontapgesture(count:perform:)); it made me change all instances of the word "Shape" to "any Shape."

The code that came the closest to working is the following, but then the line with ".onTapGesture {" receives the error "Type 'Any View' cannot conform to 'View'".

```
struct ShapeChangeGesture: View {
    let shapes: [any Shape] = [Rectangle(), Circle(), Ellipse(), Capsule()]
    
    @ State private var customShapes: any Shape = Circle()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(images[0].imgSrc)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .clipShape(customShapes)
            .onTapGesture {
                if images[0].shapeNum > 3 {
                    images[0].shapeNum = 1
                    customShapes = shapes[images[0].shapeNum]
                }
                
                else {
                    images[0].shapeNum += 1
                    customShapes = shapes[images[0].shapeNum]
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is separate the logic of shape change into an enum. Why? because dealing with indexes, and also storing all those shapes is not practical: we may not need them all, and also what if we want a different order tomorrow? or a new shape? In short, arrays are too fragile. I'd prefer enums, that can also serve me the next shape, like this:

```
enum ClippableShape: Int {
    
    case rectangle
    case circle
    case ellipse
    case capsule
    
    var next: ClippableShape {
        ClippableShape(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? .rectangle
    }
}
```

Next, I would create my custom `ViewModifier`, that, given the `ClippableShape` can convert it to `Shape` and apply it to any view:

```
struct ClippableShapeViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    private let clippableShape: ClippableShape
    
    init(clippableShape: ClippableShape) {
        self.clippableShape = clippableShape
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        switch clippableShape {
        case .rectangle:
            content.clipShape(Rectangle())
        case .circle:
            content.clipShape(Circle())
        case .ellipse:
            content.clipShape(Ellipse())
        case .capsule:
            content.clipShape(Capsule())
        }
    }
}
```

Just for convenience I would also wrap this ViewModifier into extension I can call just like with built-in `clipShape`:

```
extension View {
    
    func clipShape(_ clippableShape: ClippableShape) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ClippableShapeViewModifier(clippableShape: clippableShape))
    }
}
```

So I can now do:

```
Image(...) 
    .clipShape(.rectangle) // <-- invoking custom ViewModifier with enum value
```

Now for the source of the images. You didn't post your image array, but I assume structure like this:

```
class ImageItem: ObservableObject { // <-- observable object
    let imgSrc: String // <-- an image name, but can be anything else
    @Published var currentShape: ClippableShape = .rectangle // <-- current shape, published
    
    init(imgSrc: String) {
        self.imgSrc = imgSrc
    }
}
```

That is: we created an `ObservableObject` with `Published` property, on change of which we want to do something. And so your `View` now would do this:

```
struct ShapeChangeGesture: View {

    @ObservedObject var image = ImageItem(imgSrc: "person") // just an example, using some system image
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: image.imgSrc) // <-- show image
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 80) // changed height to be different form width, otherwise hard to see a difference between Ellipse and Circle for example
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .background(Color.red) // just to emphasize the clipped shape, no significance
            .clipShape(image.currentShape) // <-- using custom ViewModifier to clip shape
            .onTapGesture {
                image.currentShape = image.currentShape.next // <-- changing clip shape on click
            }
    }
}
```

So now you get a shape change on every click, and no need to follow the indexes.